# What the easiest way to compare datetime and and get results in minutes?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I thought this would be easier, but it hasn't been so far. I am trying to retrieve a datetime field from a stored procedure and compare it to the current DateTime.Now to get a timespan in minutes. However, when I use the code below, it returns a value that is not correct.

```
timespan = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("minute", c.dtimecre.Value, DateTime.Now).Value.ToString()
```

Assuming DateTime.Now is ‘2022-11-30 08:37:39.487’ and dtimecre is ‘2022-11-29 21:07:59.650’ – I expected to get a value of 689 but this is returning 750, not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Could it be related to timezone or daylight saving? Please note that the difference is about 1h...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [datetime.subtract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=net-7.0) and get `TotalMinutes`

```
  DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("2022-11-29 21:07:59.650");
  DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("2022-11-30 08:37:39.487");

  var result =dt2.Subtract(dt1).TotalMinutes; // reslt = 689.66395
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `DateTime.Now` and `c.dtimecre.Value` time zones are same. If there are differences, then the `DateDiff` function's result could be incorrect.

If not sure try to use `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes` property to calculate the time difference between the two DateTime values in minutes. That's not required to convert `DateTime` to a specific time zone. something like this

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.Now - c.dtimecre.Value;
double minutes = timeSpan.TotalMinutes;
```